# Difference between Array and Timeseries

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to save result to `to_file` block in model matlab
just I want to know what is difference between `array` and `timeseries` in save format field.

Comment: I think that Simulink Documentation explains this sufficiently well: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/tofile.html The timeseries is the default format, and the Array is allocated specifically for vector, double, noncomplex signals

Answer (score 1):

Lets start from array - it's easiest thing. If you use `To File` or `To Workspace` block with `array` options it writes to file just column of values of your variable.

If you use `Timeseries` it writes values in [timeseries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/time-series-objects.html) format. This structure consist of several fields. Main of them are `Time` and `Data`. So you get not only values but times corresponded to this data! Furthermore it contain some additional information like interpolation method and other (see it in help).

When I have to use `Array` and when `Timeseries`?
It's clear that if time moments important to you you need to use `Timeseries`. For example if your simulation uses variable time step then data will not be uniformly distributed.So it's helpful to get times too.

Using an array is useful if times of data is not important. For example if I save from `Enabled subsystem` only 1 value of my variable.